# How would you crack this (MD5 HashCat)?

Tags: passwords, md5, password-encryption, password-hash, hashcat

I was given this file:

hashes.txt

```
experthead:e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
interestec:25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b
ortspoon:d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4
reallychel:5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
simmson56:96e79218965eb72c92a549dd5a330112
bookma:25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad
popularkiya7:e99a18c428cb38d5f260853678922e03
eatingcake1994:fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759
heroanhart:7c6a180b36896a0a8c02787eeafb0e4c
edi_tesla89:6c569aabbf7775ef8fc570e228c16b98
liveltekah:3f230640b78d7e71ac5514e57935eb69
blikimore:917eb5e9d6d6bca820922a0c6f7cc28b
johnwick007:f6a0cb102c62879d397b12b62c092c06
flamesbria2001:9b3b269ad0a208090309f091b3aba9db
oranolio:16ced47d3fc931483e24933665cded6d
spuffyffet:1f5c5683982d7c3814d4d9e6d749b21e
moodie:8d763385e0476ae208f21bc63956f748
nabox:defebde7b6ab6f24d5824682a16c3ae4
bandalls:bdda5f03128bcbdfa78d8934529048cf
```

I thought I had to separate them, for example I put the `experthead`, `interestec`, etc. in one file named `wordtext.txt` and `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`, etc in another file called `hash.txt`.

I then ran this:

```
hashcat -m 0 -a 0 /Users/myname/Desktop/hash.txt /Users/myname/Desktop/wordtext.txt -O
```

but I couldn't get anything. And then I googled `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` and the output was `123456` so now I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the hashes (erase the plaintext) on the txt file, hashcat will sort them out by itself. What I do is: hashcat.exe -m 0 -a 0 hashFile.txt dict.txt --show

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: Wont let me, dont have enough rep points, I dont see how my answer was brief. also comments are used for clarification or to point out a problem in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The file appears to be in username:hash format. By default, hashcat assumes that only hashes are in the target file.

You can change this behavior with hashcat's `--username` option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to place the `-O` at the end. It should work perfectly without it, but you do need `hashcat.exe` in the beginning.